# To understand integral :$\lambda (x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^{2} \alpha x}{\alpha^{2}} d\mu(\alpha), (\mu(0)=0)$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, integration

I wants to understand the integrals of the form

$$\lambda (x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^{2} \alpha x}{\alpha^{2}} d\mu(\alpha),  (\mu(0)=0)$$
where $\mu(\alpha)$ is a non decreasing function such that the integral converges for all real $x.$

**Trivial Example**: If we take, $\mu(\alpha)= \alpha,$ then $\lambda (x)= |x|\frac{\pi}{2}.$

**My Questions are**:

> (1) Can you give few more examples of non decreasing function $\mu(\alpha)$, so that  we know the exact value of $\lambda (x).$ ?
>
> (2) Suppose the above integral ($\lambda (x)$) converges for the given non decreasing function $\mu(\alpha).$  Can we expect(to evolute) to get the exact(precise) values of $\lambda(x), (x\in \mathbb R)$ ?
>
> (3) Why $\lambda (x)$ in the literature it is known as "negative definite  function" ; can you motivates me  bit ? (For instance, Arne Beurling, in his paper, "on the spectral synthesis of bounded functions" called this $\lambda (x)$ as  negative definite functions)
>
> (4) Does there exists any well-known analogue  of ``negative definite functions" defined in $\mathbb R^{2} (\mathbb R^{n})$ ? If not, what one can expect ?

Thanks,

Comment: You should read some references on Stieltjes integral, for example [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StieltjesIntegral.html). For 1) you can take $\mu = \frac23 x^{3/2}$ and get $\sqrt{x\pi}$. For 2), if $\mu$ is $C^1$, $d\mu = \mu^\prime(\alpha) d\alpha$, so you can decide from this subcase.

Answer (score 5):

(1) Denote by $\mu(\alpha)$ the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{d\mu}{d\alpha}$.  Notice that if we extend $\mu(\alpha)$ to the negative reals by $\mu(-\alpha)=\mu(\alpha)$, the integral becomes
\begin{equation}-2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\alpha x}\frac{\mu(\frac{\alpha}{2})}{\alpha^2}d\alpha+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(\alpha)}{\alpha^2}d\alpha.\end{equation}
Therefore, what needs to be computed is the Fourier transform of $\frac{\mu(\frac{\alpha}{2})}{\alpha^2}$. For example, if $\mu(\frac{\alpha}{2})=\alpha^{2-p}$ where $0<p<2$, the Fourier transform is 
\begin{equation}
\frac{2(\sin \frac{\pi p}{2})\Gamma(1-p)}{|\alpha|^{1-p}},
\end{equation}
(after that the original integral is easy to compute), and you can find more examples [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform). For example, the case $\mu(\alpha)=\alpha^2\log(1+|\alpha|)$ can be computed explicitly (although the result will be a distribution).

(2) Obviously, there is no general method for these integrals, but if you know the function $\mu$ well enough, and if it is analytic, you can compute the integral by the residue theorem. So for exaple if $\mu(\alpha)$ is an even rational function such that the integral converges, it can be computed.

(3) By [Bochner's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner%27s_theorem), the Fourier transform of a nonnegative function is positive definite, so its negative is negative definite.

(4) Negative definite functions can even be defined on any group, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function_on_a_group).